# Upper limit of String split return?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split

Does anyone know if there is an upper limit to the number of returned entries when processing a String.Split? I have a string with "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..." with 600 entries but it only returns 201 entries in the returned array. Thanks!

EDIT: 
It's just one line of code, I've opened the watcher at run time to make sure the string is still has 600 comma/entries.

```
string[] splitLine = s.Split(',');
```

And the resulting splitLine array only contains 201 entries.

EDIT 2: 
Nevermind, I'm an idiot and can't count, didnt realize the string had 601 characters, which includes the commas and spaces. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I just processed 2245 entries with no problem.  Can you show the code? My guess is that it's something there.

Comment: Please post the problem with code, don't just guess what the problem is and ask for confirmation with no details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see int the source code of the String.Split method, **there is no limit to split strings**.

```
        [ComVisible(false)]
        internal String[] SplitInternal(char[] separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options)
        {
        if (count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count",
                Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NegativeCount"));

        if (options < StringSplitOptions.None || options > StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Arg_EnumIllegalVal", options));
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String[]>() != null);
        Contract.EndContractBlock();

        bool omitEmptyEntries = (options == StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if ((count == 0) || (omitEmptyEntries && this.Length == 0)) 
        {           
            return new String[0];
        }

        int[] sepList = new int[Length];            
        int numReplaces = MakeSeparatorList(separator, ref sepList);            

        //Handle the special case of no replaces and special count.
        if (0 == numReplaces || count == 1) {
            String[] stringArray = new String[1];
            stringArray[0] = this;
            return stringArray;
        }            

        if(omitEmptyEntries) 
        {
            return InternalSplitOmitEmptyEntries(sepList, null, numReplaces, count);
        }
        else 
        {
            return InternalSplitKeepEmptyEntries(sepList, null, numReplaces, count);
        }            
    }
```

**Reference:** http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,baabf9ec3768812a,references

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here, the split method returns **600 parts**.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var baseString = "1,";
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(var i=0;i<599;i++)
        {
            builder.Append(baseString);
        }
        builder.Append("1");

        var result = builder.ToString().Split(',');

        Console.WriteLine("Number of parts:{0}",result.Length);
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/oDosIp